# Не срабатывают скрипты React в Electron

Tags: reactjs, electron

После сборки electron приложения
(`"electron-build": "electron-builder"` в package.json)

При запуске приложения не срабатывают скрипты `react`.

Т.е. есть разметка с `<div id="root"></div>` но приложение не рендерится

В консоли ошибок нет
Просто локальный билд реакта работает исправно (если добавить `HashRouter` вместо `BrowserRouter`)
И так же при разработке `localhost` и `electron` работают исправно

В чём может быть проблема, почему скрипты не срабатывают, и не происходит рендер приложения в окне?

Comment: Что будет отдавать сервер на запросы с разными УРЛ?

Comment: @ksa Не совсем понял вопрос, но если подставить в ```mainWindow.loadURL('https://www.google.com/')``` (экземпляр BrowserWindow) адрес гугла, то всё работает. Как я понял, проблема в том, что билд электрона не добавляет скрипты и стили, в отличии от билда реакта

Comment: `HashRouter` не меняет "основную" часть УРЛ, добавляя `#` и потом все остальное. Значит грузится с сервера всего один файл со скриптами. `BrowserRouter` меняет уже весь УРЛ. Т.о. сервер, по этим, разным УРЛ, все равно должен отдавать один единственный "стартовый" файл.